# How to load .env file data before imports?

Tags: node.js, dotenv

I'm trying to use the `dotenv` package to load data from a .env file.

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
```

Unfortunately, some of my other modules need to load data from this when they start, and they throw an error if that data is not found, like this:

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
console.log('token',process.env.TOKEN);
import client from './client.js';
```

And in client.js, the first line is this:

```
if (!process.env.TOKEN) throw new Error(`No TOKEN provided in your .env file!`)
```

So when I run this, I get this error. I have a feeling the import statements are getting hoisted above `dotenv.config()` (the console.log isn't getting reached), and so it's running client.js before finishing the main file.

If I import / config dotenv in client.js, then it works fine, but that's not the only file that needs to check for dotenv variables.

I don't understand what I am supposed to do here, or why i even need to call `.config()` at all. How do I load the .env files before importing anything else, so that all the modules I import have access to those variables immediately?

Answer (score 0):

(i figured this out right before posting, but am posting in case someone else has the same issue)

Put the dotenv loading into it's own file, like this:

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
console.log('Loading dotenv file...');
export default true;
```

and import that before the other modules:

```
import dotenvLoad from "./dotenvLoad.js";
```

and that will force it to run the config line before continuing.

Comment: Yup, was going to say the same thing, you can also put it in an async task in the other file so that you definitely get the env variables. Although I like how commonJs handles this stuff easily like
I can just do
``` const dotenv = require('dotenv').config(); ```
and it just sets the environment variables before any other imports.
As for you question of why do we need to call `` .config() `` with dotnev is when you call dotenv.config(), it reads the contents of the .env file and adds the variables to the process.env object. This allows your application to access these variables.